# Metadata Namespacing rules in Branch Org

Tags: metadata, list, namespace, page-layout

I am using the FinancialForce Apex bindings to access the Metadata API on one of my orgs. I attempt to create and a related list to one of the Opportunity layouts. This related list refers to other custom objects in its name.

```
    MetadataService.RelatedListItem relatedList = new MetadataService.RelatedListItem();
    relatedList.fields = new List<String>{
        'NAME',
        '<NAMESPACE>CustomField1__c'
        '<NAMESPACE>CustomField2__c'
    };
    relatedList.relatedList = '<NAMESPACE>CustomObj1__c.<NAMESPACE>CustomObj2__c';
    relatedList.sortField = '<NAMESPACE>CustomField2__c';
    return relatedList;
```

The problem is assigning the `relatedList` field. I get this error:

`15:02:47:542 USER_DEBUG [74]|DEBUG|Callout Errors: Opportunity-MyLayout: Invalid related list:<NAMESPACE>CustomObj1__c.<NAMESPACE>CustomObj2__c (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION).`

This is very confusing as the issue does not reproduce in a normal DE org nor does it happen in a sandbox - it only happens in Branch Orgs.

I have tried altering the namespacing on that `relatedlist.relatedList` variable. Having the namespace on both the first and second part gives the error above, as does having the namespace only on the first. Having no namespaces on either or having a namespace only on the second part gives a obvious "failed to parse related list" error.

Thank you.